# GNU Diff Utility report as Differ where Files are Same

Tags: windows-xp, diff

I have installed **diffutils-2.8.7-1.exe** in Windows XP System.

I have created a MS Office Word Document with some text and an image.

Scenario 1:

```
Command:  diff --report-identical-files "file1.doc" "file1.doc"
```

It gives the output as **"Identical"**.

```
Action:  Now i have copy pasted the file1.doc.
```

Scenario 2:

```
Command:  diff --report-identical-files "file1.doc" "Copy of file1.doc"
```

It gives the output as **"Identical"**.

```
Action:  Now i have opened the file1.doc and Save As file2.doc
         Without doing any modification in the content.
         Visually both files look identical.
```

Scenario 3:

```
Command:  diff --report-identical-files "file1.doc" "file2.doc"
```

It gives the output as **"Differ"**.

```
Query:  Could anyone please explain how it can happen ??
        Is diff utility checks something beyond the content of the document ??
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for two `.doc` files to be different even if their contents are identical is that there are additional metadata saved in the file, and these metadata differ.

Unless you use some more intelligent comparison tool, you are out of luck. `diff` does not understand at all the `.doc` file format and thus compares every byte individually, unable to ignore what you consider as insignificant.

Comment: Is there any other tool which can work as "diff" as well as we can specify what data to be considered and what data to be ignored ??

Comment: Most comparison tools with an integrated "Word comparison" mode will do that. The tool I work for (ECMerge) uses a text extractor for that purpose. You can use it visually or from command line.